# python bitcoin_explorer can't read block 761249

Tags: block, python

I installed bitcoin node, synced up to date.
I am using python bitcoin_explorer to read the block data.
I can read all blocks, however, I can't read block 761249
I am not sure it's my syncing problem, the data break on my machine, or it's bitcoin_explorer's problem.
Anybody can help me try it on your machine please? Here is the code

```
pip install bitcoin_explorer

import bitcoin_explorer as bq

db = bq.BitcoinDB("/home/.bitcoin", tx_index = True)

block = db.get_block(761249, connected = True)

print(block['header']['block_hash'])
```

Anybody could help me try it and let me know? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Block 761249 (2022-11-01 10:44:19) contains transaction [`73be398c4bdc43709db7398106609eea2a7841aaf3a4fa2000dc18184faa2a7e`](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transactions?s=size(desc)&q=block_id(761249)#f=hash,block_id,input_count,output_count,time,output_total,size) which is size 500.142 kB and is pretty strange, it contains mostly zeroes. Some parsers interpret this as about half a million zero-length witness components.

This is about a month before Ordinals Inscription 0. No idea if this is related.

Perhaps the Python bitcoin_explorer library assumes transaction sizes never exceed 500 kB or has trouble parsing this particular transaction?

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I can see this transaction is really strange, input is 0.03682719 BTC, but output is 0. Where did the 0.03682719 BTC go?
I can use bitcoin core to access this block though, so probably it's Python bitcoin_explorer's problem.
I really want to get data for this block, including input BTC amount & addresses, output BTC amount & addresses, any other way to get it please?